# why i get error when i want to load html file in js in django project?

Tags: jquery, django

I want to load HTML file in Js file in django,but i get  this error:
Not Found: /login.html

there is this file in templates folder!

---

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#load_').load('login.html')

});

---

Answer (score 1):

You can't just include a file in templates folder an expect it to find in site's directory. Django disallows directory browsing by default. You may define an urlconf to include that html file in your urls such as:

```
path('login.html/', TemplateView(template_name="login.html"), name='login-html')
```

But this is discouraged. I think you should use a frontend framework such as React or Vue to load your templates via javascript and use services (which I think the case).